# Java - Is true non blocking achievable in Java

Tags: java, jvm, nonblocking

From my experience, I've seen that in order to support non blocking networking apis, Java does it by spawning a thread which then does the networking logic (say http call). Unlike node where there is no thread hung up on the http call. In the case of Java, the spawned thread is basically blocked.

But I've also heard that netty provides true non blocking apis? That is, no thread is blocked. Is this true?

Comment: Internally, Node also spawns a thread which waits for the http request (well, depends on the kernel). You might be interested in this article: [Understanding the Node.js Event Loop](https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-the-nodejs-event-loop/)

Comment: Yes node uses thread pools to support async for filesystem operations. for networking, epoll is used

Comment: If a process is waiting for an external event something has to wait for it, obviously. It either waits for an interruption (callback) or polls for the event. The definition of "blocked" is "waiting for an event". You cannot wait for an event without waiting for the event.

Comment: Here is my understanding, lets say we made 200 async http request in java. Assume no thread pool, then 200 threads will be created to give us the illusion of non blocking. In case of epoll, kernel does not create 200 threads for each http request. It relies on the socket which when gets ready, notifies the epoll.

Comment: Java also supports `epoll` which is wrapped into [Selector API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html).

Comment: *"no thread is blocked. Is this true?"* - No, at least one Selector thread is periodically blocked to listen for I/O events.